# How can I transcode video to HLS version 3 using Google Transcoder?

Tags: http-live-streaming, transcoding

I'm using Google Transcoder API to transcode a video to HLS file. It seems like Google Transcoder automatically transcodes my video using HLS version 4.(#EXT-X-VERSION:4) However, I want to get HLS version 3 transcoded video as a result. I haven't found any fields to specify HLS versions in the API documents. Could someone please help me to generate HLS version 3 transcoded video using Google Transcoder?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:4.004,
```

I took a look the API docs and searched the way through internet, but I haven't found any solutions, yet.